# Javers - Disable sql schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, audit, javers

In Javers and Spring, is can disable the automatic creation sql schema?
So I can create the schema with Liquibase for use multi-tenancy

Answer (score 0):

This question is unclear. You cant disable schema craeation in JaVers SQLRepository but even if you could, what would be a purpose for that? If you  create different tables than JaVers expects, it crashes.

Comment: I do not want to create different tables.
I just needed to create the same tables in more schemas beyond the 'public'.
For that extracts the creation scripts and used the Liquibase to create
Javers the tables in other schemas.
Besides Liquibase give error when a table already created, when I
multi tenancy in APPLICATION, Spring conseque not create the Beans Javers
for lack of schema

Comment: The way I found to run the application, was to remove the @PostConstruct the annotation method 'ensureSchema' class JaversTransactionalDecorato